# how to make a validation registration in php?

Tags: php, registration

```
 <form method="post" action="ins.php">
  <div class="reg_section personal_info">
  <h3>Informatii generale</h3>
 <input name="Nume" type="text" required id="Nume" placeholder="Nume" >
 <input name="Prenume" type="text" required id="Prenume" placeholder="Prenume">
   <input name="Login" type="text" required id="Login" placeholder="Login">     
 <input name="Email" type="text" required id="Email" placeholder="Email">
 <input name="date" type="text" required id="date" placeholder="Data Nasterii">
  </div>
  <div class="reg_section password">
  <h3>Parola</h3>
 <input name="password" type="password" required id="password" placeholder="Parola">
 <input name="password1" type="password" required id="password1" placeholder="Confirma parola">

 </div>
  <div class="reg_section password">
  <h3>Regiunea</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="Nord">Nord</option>
    <option value="Sud">Sud</option>
    <option value="Centru">Centru</option>
  </select>
    </div>
 </p>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign Up"></p>
  </form>


 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['Nume']))  {
        $_POST['numeEr']="Introduceti Numele!";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $_POST['Nume'])) {
    $_POST['numeEr']="Ati introdus valori gresite! Numele trebuie sa fie compus din caractere";
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['Prenume']))  {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Introduceti Numele!"> Introduceti Numele! </font>';
    } 
    else if (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $_POST['Prenume'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Ati introdus valori gresite!"> Ati introdus valori gresite! Numele trebuie sa fie compus din caractere</font>';
    }

    else if(empty($_POST['Login']))  {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Introduceti Loginul!"> Introduceti Loginul! </font>';
    } 
    else if (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $_POST['Login'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Ati introdus valori gresite!"> Ati introdus valori gresite! Loginul trebuie sa fie compus din caractere</font>';
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Introduceti Parola!"> Introduceti parola</font>';
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/\A(\w){6,20}\Z/", $_POST['password'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Parrola este prea scurta!"> Parrola trebuie sa fie mai > 6 caractere!  </font>';
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['password1'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Confirmati Parola"> Conformati parola!</font>';
    }
    else if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password1']) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Parolele nu coincid!"> Parolele nu coincid!</font>';
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Introduce-ti E-mail-ul!">Introduce-ti E-mail-ul! </font>';
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="E-mail are format incorect!"> E-mail are format incorect! </font>';
    }


    else{
        $nume = $_POST['Nume'];
        $prenume = $_POST['Prenume'];
        $login = $_POST['Login'];
        $parola=$_POST['password'];
        $parola = md5($parola);
        $parola1=$_POST['password1'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $data = $_POST['date'];  


        $query = ("SELECT id FROM utilizatori WHERE Login='$login'");
        $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            echo '<font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Loginul dat exista">Exista deja un utilizator cu Login-ul dat!</font>';
        }
        else {
            $query2 = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE Mail='$email'");
            $sql = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                echo '<font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif"  alt="Exista deja un Utilizator cu aces email!">Exista deja un Utilizator cu aces email!</font>';
            }
            else{$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO utilizatori (Nume,Prenume,Login,Parola,Data_nasterii,Mail) VALUES ('$nume','$prenume','$login','$parola','$data','$email')") or die(mysql_error()); header('location:index(2).php'); } }}}
include 'inregistrare.php';
?>
```

here is my form and connection!
How can I make warnings to appear in form in the same time? I tried many ways but nothing works, how can I correctly make this validation?

Comment: For one thing, you are missing `<?php` that should be above `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your `else if` by `if`, after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` add line `$error = false;` in every `if` in which you are validating data add line `$error = true;` and instead of `else{` in the end use `if(!$error){`.